# NSTrackingArea and performance

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit

I have a NSTrackingArea to determine whether I should show a close "button" in my view. I would like to show a rollover image.

What is better,

- Actually using a button ( as a subview ) instead of drawing my own thing, then adding another tracking area to the button and then showing the rollover image..
- Using a **second** NSTrackingArea to determine when the mouse is on top of the close button so I can show the rollover image.

I personally think the second one is easier, the only thing that I would have to do extra what the button would do for me is implementing a click action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use whichever approach is simplest for you to implement. It is extremely unlikely that either will cause any performance problems (`NSTrackingArea` is already highly optimized.)